# Craft Controller gives 404 error

Tags: plugin-development, routing

So I am working on it first time. I created a Controller `DB_DuhController` having a method `actionFoo()`

I am then calling it as `http://domain.craft.dev/admin/DB/duh/Foo` but it's giving `404` all the time. What is wrong being done by me?

Comment: Should it be `/admin/db/duh/foo` with lower case db? I think the plugin name is lowercase for first letter: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#how-controller-actions-fit-into-routing same with action name `foo` not `Foo`. Also assume you have a CP route in place for the `/admin` request.

Comment: `/admin` is working but not after that.

Comment: post your cp route.

Comment: My `hookRegisterCpRoutes` method is empty. Do I need to define routes first?

Comment: Yes unless you are accessing it with the /actions url

Comment: you mean `http://domain.craft.dev/admin/DB/duh/actions/Foo`?

Comment: I did this: `DB/duh/list' => array('action' => 'db/_list')` and it says: `Unable to resolve the request "duh/list".

Comment: @LukeHolder there?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `/actions` (or whatever your Trigger word is) to access Controller actions.

Documentation: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#actionTrigger

**EDIT:** I realize I wasn't clear enough; this variable defaults to `/actions`. Unless you've set it to something else in your Config, add the `/actions` to your URL to access the Controller action.

So, your URL would be this: `http://domain.craft.dev/actions/PluginHandle/Duh/foo`

Note that **capitalization matters.**

It's also important to make sure that if you plan on making calls to this URL from outside Craft, you'll need to make sure that you're allowing anonymous access by setting that variable at the top of your controller:

`protected $allowAnonymous = true;`

Comment: My Config does not have any such entry.

Comment: the default action trigger is 'actions' so there doesn't need to be anything in your config. just try hitting `/actions/db/dauh/foo`